# URL encode data RFC-3986 in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, urlencode, code-conversion

How do I convert this code to VB?

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns URL encoded version of input data according to RFC-3986
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data">String to be URL-encoded</param>
/// <returns>URL encoded version of input data</returns>
public static string UrlEncode(string data)
{
    StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char symbol in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
    {
        if (ValidUrlCharacters.IndexOf(symbol) != -1)
        {
            encoded.Append(symbol);
        }
        else
        {
            encoded.Append("%").Append(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", (int)symbol));
        }
    }
    return encoded.ToString();
}
```

I have tried a code converter but it errors with

> Error BC32007 'Byte' values cannot be converted to 'Char'. Use 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW' to interpret a numeric value as a Unicode character or first convert it to 'String' to produce a digit.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2) (same as suggested by Wiktor, but the english version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A converter you may used is not a programmer with deep knowledge of possibilities. It just a shallow mapper of keywords and syntax.
It gave you the following line, right?

```vb
For Each symbol As Char In Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
```

This resulted in the error you mentioned.
@jmcilhinney already gave you the **correct answer** (aka how a programmer would do it) which is actually a workaround, because to program this code correctly avoids using `GetBytes()` result as a `Char` enumerable.

But here is an other solution which solves the exact error message instead. In cases the situation not avoidable you may use this.

```vb
...
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Globalization
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
...

Public Shared Function UrlEncode(ByVal data As String) As String
   Dim encoded As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

   ' you get Bytes here...
   For Each dataByte As Byte In Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
            
      ' ... and convert to Char here
      Dim symbol = ChrW(dataByte)

      If ValidUrlCharacters.IndexOf(symbol) <> -1 Then
         encoded.Append(symbol)
      Else
         encoded.Append("%").Append(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(symbol)))
      End If
   Next

   Return encoded.ToString()
End Function
```

**EDIT:**

P.S.: Why are you using `CultureInfo.Invariant` in string to hex format at all? What difference will it make? The following seems to be enough:

```
encoded.Append("%").Append(Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(symbol).ToString("X2"))
```

**EDIT2:**

As @Heinzi pointed out @jmcilhinney's answer isn't correct.
Use mine! :)

Comment: This code is direct from an Amazon Seller Partner API example solution which I have needed to use on a vb application. Thank you for your answer, it has worked great.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is already an `IEnumerable(Of Char)` so there's no need to do anything to the `String`.

```vb
For Each symbol In data
```

That applies to C# too. The code you have is simply converting all the characters to `bytes` and then back to `chars` again, which is rather pointless.

Comment: This, however, breaks the semantics of the program: You now iterate over Unicode code points, not over UTF-8 bytes. The original program encodes the string `Ä` as `%C3%84`. Your code changes that to `%C4`, which is wrong: Percent-encoding in URLs contains byte values, not Unicode code points. (Yes, there's `%u...`, but that's not what the original code is doing.)